# Use local Azure Storage Emulator from Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin, azure-storage

Is it possible to access the local Azure Storage Emulator from an Android Emulator running the Azure Client libraries (xamarin client)?
I'm running into connection issues. 
Perhaps by specifying a proxy?

sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/InquisitorJax/Xamarin-Forms-Azure-Blob-Storage) (WIP)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following connection string:
"UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://10.0.2.2"